# Is there any better way to select option from lookup using selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have written a  code to select an text from the lookup,for that I have used thread.sleep.I wanted an alternative way to select the element from the lookup,as you can see its a time waste of 2sec by using thread.sleep.I could use explicit wait but, i have to give the element to select for it(important: here the element to be found and selected varies and its dynamic, so i have not used explicit wait).
for example: when i type "s" in a lookup i get list of values in it lets say sandeep,sandy,sad,sam .so i want to select 1st element in it.

```
    WebElement ele = driver.findElement(locator.getLocator(input1));
    ele.sendKeys(input2);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    ele.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
    ele.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    testReport.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Value from lookup got Selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to wait for the container that holds the option items to be visible.

Comment: is there any way that i can use explicit wait or some other way.As of now i have hard coded as thread.sleep.

Comment: You should be able to do something like this `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.css("someselector")));` with the selector being that of the dropdown menu